# Changing the Login Screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I am looking to change the login screen background on my laptop.

The reason for this is that, while it is a company machine, I spend 70% of my time in customer premises and not all the imagery is appropriate for customer settings, (it changes every week or so). Due to the fact that this is a large company (80,000+ employees) and I am one of the rare few who spend so long in customer premises, remote support have no interest in fixing my issue. This change is not a breech of company policy it is just a symptom of being an exception to the norm.

Whilst it is a company machine, I have local admin rights.
Until recently I had been able to change the background image by copying a neutral image into C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds. However recently a different image is appearing to the one stored there.

Any suggestions would be grateful.

The machine setup is

OS: Windows 10

Version: 1709

OS Build: 16299.551

Thank you.

V.

Comment: Group policy > users preference.

Comment: Thanks spikey_richie I had a look there, however there is nothing set except force screensaver password and for screensaver timer, which I am happy to keep as is.

Comment: That's not what I meant. > is greater than, meaning your group policy will always over-ride whatever the user chooses.

Comment: Thanks spikey_richie, however this is disabled, (the current greyed out image is the one i want).

Comment: Also I have checked the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization it is set to 1 and Group Profile has Computer Configuration > Administration Template Personalization  > Prevent Changing lock screen and logon image is set to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

We can change lock screen background like this:

1. Navigate to "**Settings -> Personalisation -> Lockscreen**",
2. Have the Lock Screen set to "**Picture**".
3. Select the picture we like.
4. Have the "**Show lock screen background picture on sign-in screen**" set to "**On**".

[image]
For details we can refer the article: [Change Lock Screen Background in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5016-change-lock-screen-background-windows-10-a.html)

**Tip:** The default lock screen background images included in Windows are located in the **C:\Windows\Web\Screen folder**.

Comment: Thanks Daisy_Zhou, however these options are disabled.

Comment: Also I have checked the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization it is set to 1 and Group Profile has Computer Configuration > Administration Template Personalization  > Prevent Changing lock screen and logon image is set to disabled.

Comment: 1. Is the computer activated?（need to activate）
2. Lock screen is enabled for both local group policies and the registry.
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization，change the value of NoLockScreen from 1 to 0 (zero)
Ensure "prevent changing lock screen and logon image" is disabled.
3. Is your computer a domain-added computer in your company? If so, it may be that the policy set by the administrator prevents the computer from changing this setting.

Comment: Hi Daisy_Zhou. Thank you, changing the registry entry has enabled it and it now works.